# How can a copy the contents of one element (a text string) and append to the contents of another element? (XML)

Tags: xml, batch-file, xpath, find, copy

I've been tasked with modifying thousands of question files. There's one question per file.

I need to a modify a file like this...

```
<xml>

<question>What is the fourth planet from the Sun?</question>

<answer choice="1">Mercury</answer>
<answer choice="2">Venus</answer>
<answer choice="3">Mars</answer>

<feedback choice="1">Incorrect.</feedback>
<feedback choice="2">Incorrect.</feedback>
<feedback choice="3">Correct.</feedback>

<extrafeedback>Mars is the fourth planet from the Sun and is the second smallest planet in the solar system. Named after the Roman god of war, Mars is also often described as the "Red Planet" due to its reddish appearance. </extrafeedback>

</xml>
```

...into this.
The "extrafeedback" has been added before the closing "answer" tags.

```
<xml>

<question>What is the fourth planet from the Sun?</question>

<answer choice="1">Mercury</answer>
<answer choice="2">Venus</answer>
<answer choice="3">Mars</answer>

<feedback choice="1">Incorrect. Mars is the fourth planet from the Sun and is the second smallest planet in the solar system. Named after the Roman god of war, Mars is also often described as the "Red Planet" due to its reddish appearance.</feedback>
<feedback choice="2">Incorrect. Mars is the fourth planet from the Sun and is the second smallest planet in the solar system. Named after the Roman god of war, Mars is also often described as the "Red Planet" due to its reddish appearance.</feedback>
<feedback choice="3">Correct. Mars is the fourth planet from the Sun and is the second smallest planet in the solar system. Named after the Roman god of war, Mars is also often described as the "Red Planet" due to its reddish appearance.</feedback>

<extrafeedback>Mars is the fourth planet from the Sun and is the second smallest planet in the solar system. Named after the Roman god of war, Mars is also often described as the "Red Planet" due to its reddish appearance.</extrafeedback>

</xml>
```

I have Notepad++ and Oxygen XML Editor, but I'm open to learning something new.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this rather easily by applying an XSLT to each of the docs. With a modified [identity transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform) with a specialized template for the `feedback/text()`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="feedback/text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="., /xml/extrafeedback" separator=" "/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With oXygen, you can configure an [XSLT transformation scenario](https://www.oxygenxml.com/doc/versions/18/ug-author/topics/xslt-transformation.html) to [apply batch transformations](https://www.oxygenxml.com/doc/versions/18/ug-author/tasks/apply-batch-transformation.html) to a set of files.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done pretty simply using PowerShell.  If you like, you can just copy this script to your clipboard, open a PowerShell console, `cd` to the directory containing a copy of your XML files, and paste.

```js
# // For each XML file...
gci *.xml | %{

    write-host -nonewline "Patching $($_.Name)... "

    # // Read its contents and cast as an XML object
    [xml]$xml = gc $_

    $extra = $xml.selectSingleNode("//extrafeedback/text()").data.trim()

    # // For each feedback element's text node not already containing $extra...
    $xml.selectNodes("//feedback/text()") | ?{ $_.data -NotMatch $extra } | %{
        $_.data += " $extra"
    }

    # // Save modified XML to original file
    $xml.save($_)
    write-host "done." -f green
}
```

PowerShell's XML parser will remove all the orphaned whitespace in your XML files.  Maybe copy a couple of XML files into a test directory and give this a test run first.  Examine the results before committing this script to your thousands of XML files.